# Angular- Inherited directive works in JS but not in Coffeescript 'has no method' error

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

In raw js, this angular directive works:

```
angular.module("main.vips").directive("confirmModal", function($modal) {
  var modalWork = function(modalInstance, $scope) {
    return modalInstance.result.then((function() {
      return console.log($scope.commentBox.text);
    }), function() {
      return console.log("Canceled");
    })["finally"](function() {
      return $scope.commentBox.text = "";
    });
  };

  var _confirmModal = function($scope) {
    return $modal.open({
      templateUrl: "vips/confirm_modal.html",
      scope: $scope,
      backdrop: true
    });
  };

  return {
    scope: {
      iconAttribute: "@"
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var modalInstance;
      modalInstance = void 0;

      this.runConfirmModal = function() {
              modalInstance = _confirmModal($scope);
      }

      $scope.commentBox = {};
      $scope.cancel = function() {
        modalInstance.dismiss();
        modalWork(modalInstance, $scope);
      };

      $scope.ok = function() {
        modalInstance.close();
        modalWork(modalInstance, $scope);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

**But in the coffescript version, it doesn't:**

```
angular.module("main.vips").directive "confirmModal", ($modal) ->
  modalWork = (modalInstance, $scope) ->
    modalInstance.result.then((->
      console.log $scope.commentBox.text
    ), ->
      console.log "Canceled"
    )["finally"] ->
      $scope.commentBox.text = ""


  _confirmModal = ($scope) ->
    $modal.open
      templateUrl: "vips/confirm-modal.html"
      scope: $scope
      backdrop: true


  scope:
    iconAttribute: "@"

  controller: ($scope, $element, $attrs) ->
    modalInstance = undefined
    @runConfirmModal = -> 
      modalInstance = _confirmModal($scope)

    $scope.commentBox = {}
    $scope.cancel = ->
      modalInstance.dismiss()
      modalWork modalInstance, $scope

    $scope.ok = ->
      modalInstance.close()
      modalWork modalInstance, $scope
```

When called from this other directive:

```
angular.module("main.vips").directive "deleteButton", ($modal) ->
  templateUrl: "vips/directives/delete-button.html"
  require: "^confirmModal"
  restrict: "AE"
  link: (scope, element, attr, ctrl) ->

    #do work for this element. When done, call confirm.
    element.on "click", (event) ->
      ctrl.runConfirmModal()
```

I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
          modalInstance.close();
          return modalWork(modalInstance, $scope);
        } has no method 'runConfirmModal'
```

Any ideas why it is not finding `'runConfirmModal'` in coffee script and what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `controller` function's return value is being set to the `ctrl` value.

Try either add an `return` at the end of the controller function (after the $scope.ok) function, or change your controller to return an api object (as far as I understand the docs) like so:

```
controller: ($scope, $element, $attrs) ->
  modalInstance = undefined
  $scope.commentBox = {}
  $scope.cancel = -> ...
  $scope.ok = -> ...

  runConfirmModal: -> modalInstance = _confirmModal $scope
```